# F# CSV Type Provider not working despite following the site's code

Tags: csv, f#

I am following the [csv type provider directions](https://fsprojects.github.io/FSharp.Data/library/CsvProvider.html) and everything works fine until I reference the field names, e.g. **firstRow.Date**.  It returns the error "**msft.fsx(362,25): error FS0039: The type 'Row' does not define the field, constructor or member 'Date'.**"  Except for some path differences, my code is exactly what is on the site.

Would someone please help me understand the problem?

---

```
#r "nuget: FSharp.Data, 4.2.7"
open FSharp.Data

[<Literal>]
let ResolutionFolder = __SOURCE_DIRECTORY__ 

type Stocks = CsvProvider<"/msft.csv", ResolutionFolder = ResolutionFolder>
let msft = Stocks.Load(__SOURCE_DIRECTORY__ + "/msft.csv").Cache()

let firstRow = msft.Rows |> Seq.head
let lastDate = firstRow.Date
```

---

Comment: It works for me in Rider on Linux, though I stripped out ResolutionFolder and just used the full path.

Comment: try removing the starting `/` in your filename. I believe its making the type provider think its at the root folder

Comment: You are right.  Changing the resolution folder to include a '/' makes it work.  If you repost as answering the question I will give you the credit.  Thank you for helping.
Answer: let ResolutionFolder = __SOURCE_DIRECTORY__ + "/"

Comment: Best to use Path.Combine() to avoid problems like that.

Comment: I dont think changing the resolution folder was the fix but rather removing the `/` from the filename. `/<filename>` means "search the root folder for a file called <filename>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're telling the type provider to search for a file in the root directory. Try changing it to using a relative path

```fs
type Stocks = CsvProvider<"./msft.csv", ResolutionFolder = ResolutionFolder>
// or
type Stocks = CsvProvider<"msft.csv", ResolutionFolder = ResolutionFolder>
```